# Not able to reimport Let's Encrypt certificate to AWS - New certificate has a key of EC_prime256v1 which is different from RSA_2048

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, tls1.2, lets-encrypt, aws-certificate-manager

When I am reimporting the certificate getting the following error messages,

New certificate has a key of `EC_prime256v1` which is different from `RSA_2048` in the current certificate. `(Service: AWSCertificateManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 13f02042-2e31-4629-bdfc-8e9180d26295; Proxy: null) Choose Previous button below and fix it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option is import `certificate` with `NEW` and link all cloudfront to the new `ARN` and delete the old ARN / certificate.